# Is the preceding clause omitted between 'and' and 'not always'?

Tags: sentence-structure, clauses

That is, if I rewrite the first sentence...

> "On the other hand, AI and digital technologies are already disrupting
> the traditional view of democracy, and [AI and digital technologies are already disrupting the traditional view of democracy] not always for the better, ensuring that processes are more inclusive."

Is my guess right? Or, ***and*** just links ***disrupting*** with the following ***ensuring*** as a parallel structure?

> On the other hand, AI and digital technologies are already disrupting
> the traditional view of democracy, ***and not always*** for the better,
> ensuring that processes are more inclusive. In fact, if anything, AI
> is strengthening the link between democracy and economics, supporting
> the manipulation of information to meet the needs of a few, and
> enabling the emergence of super economic powers that are outside
> democratic scrutiny and control. When algorithms are used to decide
> our access to information about a news item, a political candidate or
> a business, opinions and votes can shift, and potential governments be
> made or broken. Because algorithmic censorship is mostly unregulated,
> large corporations can in principle decide what information we have,
> outside the traditional democratic processes of governance and
> accountability. Moreover, these same corporations also own most of
> our, and our governments’, data by the conditions under which we use
> their products to share, store and manage information.

[Responsible Artificial Intelligence: How to Develop and Use AI in a ...](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=EEO8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=In%20fact,%20if%20anything,%20AI%20is%20strengthening%20the%20link%20between%20democracy%20and%20economics,%20supporting%20the%20manipulation%20of%20information%20to%20meet%20the%20needs%20of%20a%20few,%20and%20enabling%20the%20emergence%20of%20super%20economic%20powers%20that%20are%20outside%20democratic%20scrutiny%20and%20control.&source=bl&ots=-r6t1tFDOg&sig=ACfU3U1EyvyiXAXgx9cpzQgxEetywzjMrg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiho5PW-fT3AhXNC94KHYMjBkQQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=In%20fact%2C%20if%20anything%2C%20AI%20is%20strengthening%20the%20link%20between%20democracy%20and%20economics%2C%20supporting%20the%20manipulation%20of%20information%20to%20meet%20the%20needs%20of%20a%20few%2C%20and%20enabling%20the%20emergence%20of%20super%20economic%20powers%20that%20are%20outside%20democratic%20scrutiny%20and%20control.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the meaning is correct, but of course no-one would write a sentence like your 'corrected' version.

You could express it as *...and [this disruption is] not always [a change] for the better.*